# Does $\lfloor(4+\sqrt{11})^{n}\rfloor \pmod {100}$ repeat every $20$ cycles of $n$?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

I recently came across a post on SO, asking to calculate the least two decimal digits of the integer part of $(4+\sqrt{11})^{n}$, for any integer $n \geq 2$ (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21964541/1382251)).

The author presented a Java implementation using a `BigInteger` class and so forth, but the answer (given by someone else) was much simpler:

$$\forall n \geq 2 : \lfloor(4+\sqrt{11})^{n}\rfloor \pmod{ 100}=\lfloor(4+\sqrt{11})^{n+20}\rfloor \pmod {100}.$$

So in essence, we only need to calculate $(4+\sqrt{11})^{n}$ for every $n$ between $2$ and $21$.

I have unsuccessfully attempted to find a counterexample, using a `BigRational` class and [a fast-converging $n$th-root algorithm for calculating $\sqrt[n]{A}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm).

My question is then, how can we prove or refute the conjecture above?

Pardon my tags on this question, wasn't sure what else to put besides `irrational-numbers`.

Comment: Could you perhaps link to the SO post?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for m.SE, but it is an interesting question!

Comment: @quid, done; thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Consider the linear recurrence relation $a_{n+2} = 8a_{n+1} - 5a_n$ with $a_0 = 2$ and $a_1 = 8$. It is clear that $a_n$ is an integer for all $n \geq 0$. Also, this recurrence has the following closed-form solution for all $n \geq 0$:

$a_n = (4+ \sqrt{11})^n + (4 - \sqrt{11})^n$

Since $0 < 4 - \sqrt{11} < 1$, it follows that $\lfloor(4+ \sqrt{11})^n\rfloor = a_n - 1$ for all $n \geq 0$. Periodicity of $\lfloor(4+ \sqrt{11})^n\rfloor$ follows almost immediately now: first we check that $54 = a_{2} \equiv a_{22} \text{ mod } 100$ [Edit: and $92 \equiv a_{3} \equiv a_{23} \text{ mod } 100$]. Since $a_n$ is defined via a linear recurrence, it follows that $a_n \equiv a_{n+20} \text{ mod } 100$ for all $n \geq 2$, so $\lfloor(4+ \sqrt{11})^n\rfloor \equiv \lfloor(4+ \sqrt{11})^{n+20}\rfloor \text{ mod } 100$ for all $n \geq 2$ as well.

Comment: Very nice!  I was actually expecting the answer to be no.

Comment: @Nathaniel Johnston: Thank you very much! Can you please explain how you came up with $a_{n+2}=8a_{n+1}−5a_{n}$, where $a_{0}=2$ and $a_{1}=8$ to begin with?

Comment: @barak -- Sure. I wanted the polynomial whose roots are $(4 + \sqrt{11})$ and $(4 - \sqrt{11})$, which turns out to be $x^2 - 8x + 5$, which corresponds to the linear recurrence I wrote. The initial conditions $a_0 = 2$ and $a_1 = 8$ were just chosen to make the answer "clean" -- they don't really matter.

Comment: Nice answer. Just, perhaps I am confused, but why don't you need to check also the congruence for a *second* value?

Comment: @quid -- Whoops. You're not confused. You do also have to check that $a_3 \equiv a_{23} \text{ mod } 100$ (fortunately that's true).

Comment: @barakmanos: It may help you to first read an explanation of why the Fibonacci numbers have the closed form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}\right)$.  There's a general process for going getting closed forms of linear recurrences the same way, and Nathaniel just ran that process backwards starting with $(4+\sqrt{11})^n + (4-\sqrt{11})^n$.

Comment: @Nathaniel Johnston: You've just given me an assertion that I had a "good hunch" on this one, as prior to submitting this post, I was trying to think of a 2nd-degree polynomial equation such that one of its two roots would be $4+\sqrt[2]{11}$ (though I wasn't quite sure how to actually calculate such equation, and what should I "be doing with it" afterwards)... Thank you!

Comment: @Noah Snyder: Thanks.

Comment: Actually i am the one who asked that ques on stackoverflow .Can u just tell me why we have to check congruence for a second value ...some material or tutorial ??

Comment: @T.J.  Once you know $a_2 \equiv a_{22}$ and $a_3 \equiv a_{23}$ the recurrence tells you $a_4 = 8a_3-5a_2 \equiv 8a_{23}-5a_{22} = a_{24}$.  Now just do that over and over again.

Comment: ohh thanks @NoahSnyder