# What does alternating mean?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

My teacher ask a question to me.

Question is:
Determine in how many ways can be rearranged the letters of the word ECEHUCDE so that the consonants and vowels are alternating.

I said it must be $\displaystyle \frac{8!}{3!\cdot 2!}=3360$. After that i realize alternating means something different.

I did 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 => $\displaystyle \frac{24\cdot 24}{3!\cdot 2!}=48$. He said it is wrong too.

I can't find the solution because I don't know what does alternating mean?

Thank you for your all helps :)

Good day.

Comment: The solution is 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 + 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1. 

**(24*24*2)/(3!*2!)** am i right?

Comment: Yes, see my answer confirming this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c$ denote a consonant, and $v$ denote a vowel. We have four letters of each type. Consonants are C, H, D, and vowels are E, U. Alternating means an arrangement such as $\;c\,a\,c\,a\,c\,a\,c\,a\;$ or $\;a\,c\,a\,c\,a\,c\,a\,c.\;$ That is, no consonant can be next to a consonant, and no vowel can be next to a vowel.

Responding to your comment: Yes, the **bold-face** in your comment is correct. Good work!

In summary, we have that there are $$\dfrac{2\cdot (4!)^2}{3!2!} = 2\cdot 48 = 96$$
distinct ways to arrange the given letters such that the arrangement alternate between consonants and vowels.

Comment: I can try to vote +1 but I cant :( Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: Don't worry about it. I appreciate your acceptance and good intentions!

Comment: A ha. Now I understand all the sudden down-votes to old and unrelated questions of mine on this website. Somebody down-voted you, so you concluded it was me (being the only other user answering this question here), and now you're taking out all the frustration on me??? That's very mature!

Comment: @barak What are you talking about? I think it is *you* jumping to conclusions. Your answer is fine, and helpful as an alternative approach. I saw that both you and I had been downvoted here, and I concluded it was my "stalker" in action (I get one or two downvotes almost daily on correct, unproblematic questions. That's been going on long before your entrance to MSE, so I had no reason to believe you downvoted me.) It seems both our answers were  targets yesterday.

Comment: Possibly I am jumping to conclusions, though I did have a somewhat solid ground for suspicion after seeing your comment above in conjunction with 3 or 4 down-votes that have occurred since, some of which on rather old posts of mine (such as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/687736/131263). In any case, if the conclusions were wrong, then I apologize.

Comment: @barak It never crossed my mind that you downvoted my answer. Particularly since you received one too. There are times where all answers to a particular question are downvoted, but I've only seen that done when it's a very poor question showing no effort on the part of the OP. Here, I think the OP put in a sincere effort, and was in part, asking for clarification, as well as answer verification. So I really can't make any sense of it. But you certainly did not deserve a downvote, nor do I think I did. That said, someone(or a handful) seems to have an agenda that escapes my understanding.

Comment: @barak You might want to consider flagging your answers that were downvoted, but the mods are limited in what they can do, unless a long-term pattern has shown itself. But it can't hurt?

Comment: Thought about it, but wasn't sure what to write in the flag...

Answer (score 0):

There are $48$ **different** ways to put EEEU in the odd places and CCDH in the even places:

$\binom43\cdot\binom11\cdot\binom42\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11=48$

There are $48$ **different** ways to put EEEU in the even places and CCDH in the odd places:

$\binom43\cdot\binom11\cdot\binom42\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11=48$

Hence there are $96$ ways to arrange EEEUCCDH with the consonants and vowels alternating.